# How can I import mjml into my nodejs script?

Tags: node.js, mjml

Forgive my ignorance, but why can't I import mjml into my nodesjs script as described in their documentation? ...

import mjml2html from "mjml";

I have installed mjml with "npm install mjml" as instructed in my hugo project.

The error I get ...

undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils.js'